# How to utilize -> when used in a constructor?

Tags: c++

How exactly does -> do in this situation? I know you can use it in combination with `auto` and `decltype`, but I have never seen it used in a constructor like this example. I also know it can be used to pointers.

```
struct Node {
    Node() -> Node {
    // ?
    };
    // ?
    Node() -> Node();
};
```

but I have no idea what this implementation is intending.

Comment: What is the return type of a constructor???? Have you ever seen one?

Comment: @Klaus I rephrased my question. I possibly do not know what the -> means. I have only utilized it with pointers and lambda return type identifiers.

Comment: Where does this come from? It doesn't even compile

Comment: Again: There is NO return in a constructor. NO! Not void or something else. So you can't declare it with "old" syntax and also not with "->" or with any other hack. A constructor has NO return type.

Comment: @Klaus thanks for the answer, so I guess the answer is wether or not the compiler allows it, does not mean it is correct.

Comment: Which compiler did NOT complain about your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How exactly does -> do in this situation?

It makes the code not compile. This is illegal syntax.

For non-constructor member functions and free functions declared as returning `auto`, the `->` syntax after the parenthesis specifies the return type, which constructors do not have.